# Make a tool that creates an instance of a Portfolio class and fills it with stock holdings. (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

It is from Aaron Hillegass. Objective-C Programming. 
Challenge 19:

Using the StockHolding class from a previous challenge, make a tool that creates an instance of a Portfolio class and fills it with stock holdings. A portfolio can tell you what its current value is.

If I try just count it in main - I have true result in console (33772.80):

```
CGFloat sum = 0;
        for (StockHolding *n in portfolio) {
            sum += n.valueInDollars;
        }
        NSLog(@"%.2f", sum);
```

Please help me to find bug and fix it.
Big thanks!

*StockHolding.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface StockHolding : NSObject

{
    CGFloat purchaseSharePrice;
    CGFloat currentSharePrice;
    NSUInteger numberOfShares;
    NSString *nameOfShare;
}

@property CGFloat purchaseSharePrice, currentSharePrice;
@property NSUInteger numberOfShares;
@property NSString *nameOfShare;

- (CGFloat)costInDollars;
- (CGFloat)valueInDollars;

@end
```

*StockHolding.m*

```
@implementation StockHolding
@synthesize purchaseSharePrice, currentSharePrice, numberOfShares, nameOfShare;

- (CGFloat)costInDollars
{
    return purchaseSharePrice * numberOfShares;
}
- (CGFloat)valueInDollars
{
    return currentSharePrice * numberOfShares;
}

@end
```

*Portfolio.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StockHolding.h"

@interface Portfolio : NSMutableArray

- (CGFloat)totalPortfolio;

@end
```

*Portfolio.m*

```
#import "Portfolio.h"
#import "StockHolding.h"

@implementation Portfolio

- (CGFloat)totalPortfolio
{
    CGFloat sum = 0;
    for (StockHolding *n in self) {
        sum += n.valueInDollars;
    }
    return sum;
}

@end
```

*main.m*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StockHolding.h"
#import "Portfolio.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {


        StockHolding *DHL = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
        [DHL setNameOfShare:@"DHL"];
        [DHL setPurchaseSharePrice:345.67];
        [DHL setNumberOfShares:23];
        [DHL setCurrentSharePrice:389.23];

        StockHolding *Sony = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
        [Sony setNameOfShare:@"Sony"];
        [Sony setPurchaseSharePrice:587.12];
        [Sony setNumberOfShares:14];
        [Sony setCurrentSharePrice:603.81];

        StockHolding *EPAM = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
        [EPAM setNameOfShare:@"EPAM"];
        [EPAM setPurchaseSharePrice:178.45];
        [EPAM setNumberOfShares:35];
        [EPAM setCurrentSharePrice:190.64];

        StockHolding *BELAZ =[[StockHolding alloc] init];
        [BELAZ setNameOfShare:@"BELAZ"];
        [BELAZ setPurchaseSharePrice:24.43];
        [BELAZ setNumberOfShares:89];
        [BELAZ setCurrentSharePrice:108.93];

        Portfolio *portfolio = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:DHL, Sony, EPAM, BELAZ, nil];


        NSLog(@"%.2f", [portfolio totalPortfolio]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

My problem looks like:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkvopvqkhdeb5z6/portfolio.png

Comment: I'm not sure you've explained what the problem is? Your first bit of code has a variable called `result` but I can't see that in the rest of your code?

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed it. portfolio instead result

Comment: OK, so whats the actual bug you've got? Where is it not calculating it properly?

Comment: Shot of my bug report in the end of it case.

Comment: I think that my problem in Portfolio.m/.h because I have true calculate construction but if i put it in new class Portfolio and try to call method from main - I see this...

Answer (score 1):

This line...

```
Portfolio *portfolio = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:DHL, Sony, EPAM, BELAZ, nil];
```

should be

```
Portfolio *portfolio = [[Portfolio alloc] initWithObjects:DHL, Sony, EPAM, BELAZ, nil];
```

Comment: Yeah, I think the same. But i still have this wrong: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/6g3o5dgzv0qms9l/portfolio2.png]

Comment: Maybe I have problem with something references?